# Re-opening question about Installing PostGIS into schema other than public?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, duplicate-questions

I believe that [Add PostGIS spatial functions to a custom schema other than "public" in PostgreSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87212) *shouldn't* have been closed because it's *not* a duplicate of [Using schema other than public in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43187)

If anything, the first question is the *opposite* of the second question.

The second question is asking whether PostGIS features can be used with objects that themselves are not in the `public` schema. The first question covers whether the PostGIS extension and its objects can be *installed*, themselves, into a schema other than `public`.

Should the "duplicate" be re-opened?

Comment: I've reopened https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87212/add-postgis-spatial-functions-to-a-custom-schema-other-than-public-in-postgres?noredirect=1 which I had closed as duplicate after three years without activity. I still find the question text confusing but maybe that's because it's midnight here. I'll have another look tomorrow.

Comment: @underdark I noticed that the lock from merge stayed in place even after your re-open so I just unlocked the question manually.  It should now be ready for any clarifications and answers from anyone in the community.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you mark my original 'migrated' question as a duplicate of the now-re-opened question?

Comment: I think that question is best deleted because it is a question about a disputed duplicate question i.e. Meta rather than one suitable for Main. I cannot see a reason for turning it into a duplicate. Are you asking because you are trying to restore its answer?  If so, and if you can see that in its deleted state, I think you should just copy/paste it into a new answer on the question @underdark re-opened.

Comment: @PolyGeo One reason for turning it into a duplicate is that the specific text of the question is different and thus it could be (potentially) found by different searches. I already restored my answer on the re-opened question. Thanks for your help with all of this by-the-way!

Comment: I agree, many duplicates make great signpost questions. However, all content in that question is Meta i.e. it is about the differences between two other questions. Such clarifications would be better made within the two now non-duplicate questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you add a comment to it linking to the 'original' question? That'd suffice to let it serve as a good signpost.

Comment: Sorry, I can see no point in adding a comment to a migrated question which the Roomba will automatically delete.  The problem with the question you asked on Main was that it should have been asked on Meta.  Hence its migration.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can I create another duplicate then to 'signpost' that same title?

Comment: The idea is NOT to create intentional duplicates. The signpost idea is just a reason why inadvertent duplicates do not usually get deleted.  I'm happy to be pointed at a clear precedent to something that supports your proposal, so that I can review it, to double-check my interpretation of SE and GIS SE guidelines.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm torn about the creation of duplicates. I don't want to create work for anyone. On other SE sites, I could (I think) create and close the duplicate myself. But maybe even better than that would be just to comment on the question and use whatever title or terms and then that could serve as the signpost instead. I created a meta-meta question about the duplicates [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314117/deliberately-create-a-duplicate-to-be-closed-to-serve-as-a-signpost-for-di).

Comment: I think using comments for anything beyond helping a poster to improve their post is a stretch.

Comment: @PolyGeo Really? I frequently find helpful comments on questions as a person searching for an answer. The point of answering a question isn't just to help the poster.

Comment: That sounds like a discussion in comments rather than focused Q&A. The point of asking and answering questions is primarily for future visitors. Anything the asker gets out of it is the bonus they deserve for taking the time to ask a focused question. Posts are commented on to help posters get them in shape for future visitors to instantly recognize questions and whether they have been suitably answered.

Comment: @PolyGeo How is pointing providing an alternate form of a question, so that future visitors can even *find* that question, not part of the mission of providing "focused Q&A"? Or do you think that alternate forms should be included in the question itself?

Comment: Focused Q&A is ideally provided by questions and answers alone. It was just before my time, but I understand that to be the way it was in the beginning of SO. Focused Q&A is not easy. That's why comments were introduced to grease the wheels by giving others a means to help people improve their posts by suggesting/asking clarifications. Some people use comments for multiple other purposes but I think to do so starts to throw sand into the grease.  Grease helps, sand in grease does not.

Comment: I use comments sometimes to link related questions to the visited question. Such related questions will appear in the “linked questions” section (right bar).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, obviously the question that my question was *deliberately* duplicating should not have been closed and thus *should* be re-opened. The question that should be re-opened is the *opposite* of the question of which it is supposedly a duplicate.

@Vince commented on my since-migrated deliberate duplicate:

> Posting a duplicate isn't the best way to protest duplication closure.

What *is* the best way to "protest" a duplication closure? Create a meta question? Unfortunately, I couldn't comment on the original erroneously closed 'duplicate'; nor can I on my question now that it's been migrated and closed.

Comment: Even worse, the answers get migrated from one non-duplicate to another and you're left with an incomprehensible mess of answers to different questions.

Comment: You seem to have the comment everywhere privilege (50 rep) so why couldn't you comment on the "original erroneously closed 'duplicate'"?  Alternatively, you can always flag and use the Other reason to explain why your efforts to post your answer by other means have been unsuccessful. If you already did these just let us know.

Comment: If no moderator reviewing such a flag felt qualified to judge the re-opening then they most likely would have suggested posting a Meta Q&A like this one.

Comment: @PolyGeo On the original erroneously closed duplicate question, under the comments, I see the text "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews".

Comment: @PolyGeo That question should definitely be re-opened by-the-way; I'm confident that I'm qualified to judge.

Comment: It looks like the duplicate was also merged - hence the automated lock. I see a flag on it from the last few hours which did not reach me so I'll try to find how that got processed.

Comment: Yes, if you think a question should be reopened, please post the request on meta. That's the preferred approach since it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions. PolyGeo's actions here were absolutely correct.

Comment: @KennyEvitt just a side note: if you view the timeline on your question, you will see, that the only thing polygeo did, was unlocking your question. Here is the link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/87212/timeline

Comment: @MrXsquared Thanks! I don't remember any of this really now, but I edited my answer here to remove the comments about PolyGeo (as they did earlier). The unlocking happened after I posted this answer (and I only discovered that just now, thanks to you). I think what I was attributing to PolyGeo is what is shown in the timeline as "post merged" – that event is attributed to any users. But this is all mostly speculation now.

Comment: @MrXsquared I don't think you can see my original 'duplicate' answer – I see it *here* on this Meta question as a 'hidden post' (answer) and that's the result of what I think one of the things I attributed to PolyGeo. I'm happy with the current state of everything – all's well that ends well!